# simple_html_dom in php. error: call to member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, dom

Error producing code:

```
function find($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false) {
        return $this->root->find($selector, $idx, $lowercase);
}
```

I am using simple_htm_dom to parse an html string and calculate number of occurrences of certain words in certain tags. When I run the php file in a browser, the results are correctly displayed. But when it is run in Eclipse using PDT, it gives the above error of call on a non-object. I have tried debugging it and it says that $this->root is not set. But running the code in browser gives correct results.

I have looked around and this issue has been posted quite often. Someone has also submitted a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2949098&group_id=218559&atid=1044037) with a workaround. Using his workaround doesn't give me any results at all because $this->root is never set.

Answer (score 0):

Before you access `$this->root` you need to ensure whether or not it contains the object you expect.

If it does not contain the object you expect, ensure that you are invoking the function properly, e.g. if you call that function when you execute it in the browser, the class might be used differently then when you execute the single file in eclipse console.

You can as well open the page in a browser from within eclipse.

You can for both cases (browser or console) run the debugger. Debugging normally shows you where the root of the cause is lying and you can then decide how to solve it.

Comment: You said the class might be used differently. How is that possible and how can I know about the difference in behavior?

Comment: That highly depends on the definition of the class (you have not showed much of your code so it's hard to say) and how the object is created then. For example if you do not assign something to `$this->root` it remains empty. This can be possible because the CLI php configuration differs from the php configuration when you launch it in the browser, for example include pathes, modules etc. Also if you don't do error checks in the important places you might run into problems you don't understand at first glance in case of an error.

Comment: As long as `$this->root` is not set, it's not an error of the dom library, but an error of your script because you are responsible for `$this` all alone.